# Run python script inside java on android

Tags: java, android, python

Is it possible to run "**python**" script inside "**Java**" in an android app?
The main app will be **Java** but some cryptography should be done in "**python**"
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Python Integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119696/java-python-integration)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898765/calling-python-in-java

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I want to create android app!!!

Comment: then read this first : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120130/programming-android-apps-in-jython

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a python script inside android app is not practical at the moment, but what you can do is creating a HTTP web service for interpreting python and sending back the results to the android application.

Then it's just Android app communicating with a HTTP web service which is simpler than packing an interpreter.

This way it makes the app lighter too.