# Is it possible to use python and kotlin to build android project?

Tags: python, android, kotlin, kivy, python-for-android

I'm building an android application and I have some scripts in python I want to use (and not to translate) in this very project.

Right now I'm using 'Chaquopy' to make it work but I dont like the SDK it self, sometimes it crushes my app, and it restricted to use 5 minutes of the app.

the only choice for now is either to pay for it or to publish my code (which is not ready yet) in GitHub - and keep it up to date to avoid the restrictions.

So here I ask if anyone can guide me to other packages that provide the same service without the this hassle...

my python scripts job - downloading a GZ file, getting the file inside it, reading and tranfersing XML to JSON and return to my kotlin JSON text.

I read about Kivy but it seems to build full Python application in android and I can't use it as kotlin+python in the same project..

I'd appreciate any help/guidelines
thanks.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but I would simply port the Python code to Kotlin if I were you if it's as simple as you described. You may also try compiling your Python code using Jython. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11122066/2011147) for example.

Comment: There's a list of active Python-on-Android projects [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Android). Don't waste your time with Jython, I've never seen anyone claim to have got it working on Android.